# How can I restore a directory deleted from CVS after committing the change?

Tags: cvs

Once a directory has been removed using `cvs remove <dir>` and `cvs commit`, is there an easy way to undo the change - to restore the directory in my working copy and in the repository?  So far I've only been able to find suggestions which would help if I hadn't done the commit yet, or if it were a file instead of a directory.  If possible, I'd like to preserve the history of the directory's contents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Answering my own question as I figured it out.)

To restore a deleted directory after the delete has been committed:

```
cvs update -d -R -j <rev2> -j <rev1> <dir>
```

Where:

`<rev2>` is the revision which resulted from committing the remove.

`<rev1>` is the revision immediately before rev2.

`<dir>` is the deleted directory.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose that you've commited a file, but this ended up breaking something horribly. Here's how to undo your commit:

Get the version number from after the commit. You can use an $Id$ tag within the file, or cvs status. Let's say that the new version is 1.5.
Get the version number from before the commit. Typically, this will be one lower than the current version. Let's say that the old version is 1.4.
Now do this:

```
cvs update -j 1.5 -j 1.4 filename
```

cvs commit filename
The above is an example of a merge. You've asked cvs to take the difference between versions 1.5 and 1.4 and apply them to your working copy. The ordering of version numbers is significant - think of it as removing changes, or going backward in version history.

Comment: As I said in the question, advice which works for files doesn't help, because the item which has been deleted is a directory.

Comment: The answers from bythescruff and Satya saved me. The files in the directory I was trying to recover all had different revisions, so I first restored the directory using bythescruff's answer, then restored the individual files using Satya's answer. Thanks to both of you.